# How to overlay a boxplot and a lineplot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have created a box plot. Then I wanted to draw a line that represents the mean value of each box-plot. I am dealing with a problem of not overlaying. The line plot starts from a point earlier than the box-plot:

[image]

The red line should be moved one point further. My code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt


my_list=[]
label=[]
filenames = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.endswith('.dat')]
my_mean = []
for filename in filenames:
#     df = pd.read_csv('fras2009_flat_r9_parameters.dat', sep="\s+", header=None)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep="\s+", header=None)

    
    beta = df[4]
    beta = beta.drop(beta.index[0:100])
    beta_1 = pd.to_numeric(beta, errors='coerce')
    my_list.append(beta_1)
    mean = beta_1.mean()
    my_mean.append(mean)
    

#     mean.index = np.arange(1,len(mean)+1)
    #label.append(filename)
labels = ['C_r 03','C_r 05','C_r 0.1','C_r 0.2','C_r 0.5','C_r 1','C_r 2','Unconfined']

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(label)),label)
plt.boxplot(my_list,labels=labels)
# _, ax = plt.subplots()
# # mean.plot(ax=ax)
plt.plot(my_mean,color='r')
```

Comment: `plt.plot(np.arange(len(my_mean))+1, my_mean, color='r')` and  `plt.xticks(np.arange(len(label))+1, label)` should also let the lineplot start from position `1`, just like the boxplots.  Note that `plt.plot` should be called earlier than `plt.xticks`.  If you have `plt.boxplot` later than `plt.plot` the labels will be set via the boxplot, so no need to set them again.

Comment: @JohanC it worked, Shall I answer my question by my own? in order to not become down by the stack

Comment: For future reference: it would really help for reproducibility if you cleaned up your code and provided a minimum working example. Most of it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [boxplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) are by default indexed starting from `1`. This indexing could be changed by using `positions=...`. Or you could just start the `lineplot` one position further. If you call `boxplot` later than `lineplot`, it will set the correct tick labels.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['C_r 03', 'C_r 05', 'C_r 0.1', 'C_r 0.2', 'C_r 0.5', 'C_r 1', 'C_r 2', 'Unconfined']

my_list = [np.random.uniform(10, 30, 5) for _ in labels]
my_mean = [values.mean() for values in my_list]

plt.plot(np.arange(len(my_mean)) + 1, my_mean, color='r')
plt.boxplot(my_list, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]